# Should the try/except be placed in the function declaration or call?

Tags: python, try-catch, pep8

Both these snippets do the same thing:

Try/except in function declaration:

```py
def something():
    try:
        # code goes here
    except:
        print("Error")
        sys.exit(1)

something()
```

Try/except in function call:

```py
def something():
    # code goes here

try:
    something()
except:
    print("Error")
    sys.exit(1)
```

Is there one that is better/more Pythonic/recommended by PEP8 or is it just up to personal preference? I understand that the second method would get tedious and repetitive if the function needs to be called more than once, but assuming the function is only called once, which one should I use?

Comment: That depends: would you ever expect the caller of `something` to be able to do anything constructive (i.e., other than exit) in the event of an error?

Comment: Look at the bigger picture. If your function were to be used in a productive environment, where a lot of stuff happens before/after your function is called (e.g. opening file handles, starting DB transactions, ...) and your function would call ``sys.exit(1)`` then you're not giving the caller any chance to exit gracefully (e.g. closing file handles, rolling back DB transactions, ...).

Comment: @MikeScotty `sys.exit` throws a `SystemExit` exception, and hence any `finally` blocks will still run so things should get cleaned up

Answer (score 0):

the general rule is "only catch exceptions you can handle", see [here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/329714) for an explanation

note that an uncaught exception (in most languages) will cause the program to exit with an unsuccessful status code (i.e. your `sys.exit(1)`), it will probably also print out a message saying that an exception occurred.  your demo therefore is emulating default behaviour, but doing it worse

further, you're catching **every** exception and this is generally bad style, e.g. you'll implicitly catch [`SystemExit`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#SystemExit) and other internal exceptions that you probably shouldn't be dealing interacting with